# linking error on adding new file/class to ios project

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am getting a build failure on link after adding a new .h and .m file dataparsing and i don't quite understand why. I'm newer to objective-c though.  if i remove the include ( then i have to remove the reference to the object from the file that needs dataparsing class) then it wont fail. just removing the object wont cut it and it still fails when i try to include the files. in the error section under linking it says one duplicate symbol for architecture i386

dataparsing.h is:

```
//
//  dataParsing.h
//  TelnetToICC
//
//  Created by **** on 10/8/12.
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface dataParsing : UIView
{


}
- (void)getData:NSString:id;
-(void) parseLine:id;
-(void) parseDatagram:id;
-(void) reset;

@end

char icc_data[10000];
int data_top=-1;
```

the idea is just to write some simple functions for processing strings so i am not trying to do anything real special here but i'm newer to objective-c. The include for dataparsing in ViewController.m is:

```
#import "dataParsing.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreFoundation/CFSocket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

@implementation ViewController
```

It seems like i got something going on twice for the linker but my experiments havent found it. I noticed both my .h files have

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

but i remove one and it doesn't work.

Mike

Comment: What is the duplicate symbol? The error will tell you if you look at the full error message.

Comment: /Users/adams161/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TelnetToICC-etyvzjlseyeoijcufezdrzihcbja/Build/Intermediates/TelnetToICC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TelnetToICC.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/adams161/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TelnetToICC-etyvzjlseyeoijcufezdrzihcbja/Build/Intermediates/TelnetToICC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TelnetToICC.build/Objects-normal/i386/dataParsing.o

Comment: oh it says uplicate symbol _data_top in:

Comment: i changed data_top to dataTop and i still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate symbol is `_data_top`. And I'm guessing also `_icc_data`. The problem is that you are declaring a global variable in the **dataparsing.h** file. So for every file that includes this .h file, a new global variable with the same name is created resulting in the duplicate symbol linker error.

What you need to do is change the lines:

```
char icc_data[10000];
int data_top=-1;
```

to:

```
extern char icc_data[10000];
extern int data_top;
```

Then in the **dataparser.m** file you do:

```
char icc_data[10000];
int data_top = -1;
```

The extern in the .h file lets the compiler and linker know that there will be one copy of the variable defined somewhere. The lines in the .m file are that one definition.

Comment: when i do that in the .h i get extern has an intilizer warning for the dataTop line and in the .m i get redefinition of dataTop. icc_data didnt error out.

Comment: got if figured out, build succeeds now. for the extern line i left in the = -1 when i was suppose to just reference the variable name and assign it initially in the .m only. you wrote it out write i missed that distinction at first.

Comment: just curious in the .m when i include char icc_data[10000];
int dataTop=-1;  does it matter if i put that above or below @implemenation

Comment: Since they are globals and not part of the class, you should put them before `@implementation`. After the `#import` statements is a good place.

Comment: cool lot to think about in terms of how i organize the program. but i learned something and it's working. thanks guys